# uploading image using the api from the cloudinary but still after selecting image it is asking to select image and loading is done

Tags: reactjs, json, image, cloudinary

I used the API from the Cloudinary to upload image but even after selecting the image is is asking to select the image though the image is selected and the loading goes but image is not uploading.

CODE THAT I HAVE WRITTEN:

```
const postDetails = (pics) => {
    setLoading(true);
    if(pic===undefined) {
      toast({
        title: "Please Select an Image!",
        status: "warning",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
        position: "bottom",
      });
      return;
    }

    if(pics.type === "image/jpeg" || pics.type === "image/png") {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file",pics);
      data.append("upload_present", "chat-app");
      data.append("cloud_name", "*******");
      fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/******* ", {
        method: "post",
        body: data,
      }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setPic(data.url.toString());
          console.log(data.url.toString());
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          setLoading(false);
        });
    } else {
        toast({
          title: "Please Select an Image!",
          status: "warning",
          duration: 5000,
          isClosable: true,
          position: "bottom",
      });
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

On the 3rd line of the code you shared (below), `pic` is undefined. Assuming you intended to use `pics` instead.

```
if(pic===undefined)
```